# Does the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ for $s\in\mathbb{C} \ \backslash \ \{1\}$ require Cauchy's integral formula?

Tags: riemann-zeta, cauchy-integral-formula, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

I've seen Cauchy's integral formula used in proofs for the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function to the entire complex plane ($s\neq1$). My question is whether a counterexample can be given that does not require the use of Cauchy's integral formula at all to achieve the above analytic continuation for the zeta function.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Cauchy's integral formula is at all an essential item is such a proof... because not everything _does_ have an analytic continuation, so something substantially more would be needed. If you could expand on the literal argument you're meaning to refer to, that would help people understand the substance of your question (and your previous one, commented-upon by @reuns).

Comment: My interest is with regard to how Cauchy's integral formula effectively defines each value of a function non-locally via the arithmetic mean of values on an enclosing boundary. I am wondering if this mean-value property could have any bearing on the unique behavior of the zeta function in its analytically-continued domain.

Comment: Ah... thanks for the clarification. I think that Cauchy's formula itself cannot readily distinguish zeta, because linear combinations of $L$-functions (e.g., studied by Bombieri and Hejhal) are known to have infinitely-many zeros off the line. And zeta functions of quaternion algebras provably have $100\%$ of their zeros off the line.

Answer (score 0):

A proof using zero theorem:

For $s>1$

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-s}=\sum_{n\ge 1}s\int_n^\infty x^{-s-1}dx$$ $$=s\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor x^{-s-1}dx= \frac{s}{s-1}+s\int_1^\infty f_1(x)x^{-s-1}dx$$
where $f_1(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is one-periodic.

Given $f_n$ one-periodic let $c_n=\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$ and $f_{n+1}(x)=\int_1^x (f_n(y)-c_n)dy$ which is one-periodic again then $$(s+n-1)\int_1^\infty f_n(x)x^{-s-n}dx= c_n+(s+n-1)(s+n)\int_1^\infty f_{n+1}(x)x^{-s-n-1}dx$$
is analytic for $\Re(s) > -n$.

Whence by induction $\zeta(s)-\frac{s}{s-1}$ is entire.

Comment: What do you mean by "one-periodic?"

Comment: With period 1 and mean value $c_n$

Comment: Anything unclear

Comment: Can you provide any sources to this proof?

Comment: A source for what, which step do you not understand?

Comment: Is this your own proof and/or has it been published before?

Comment: What does it change?